# How to test Integration of two separate URL and test them in selenium

Tags: selenium

I have administrator and front end section I have to upload a document in administrator eg-www.admin.com and moderate  this document then it will display  on frontend

Now we have to open  new front end application  in same session and validate  correct data is displaying or not 
Pls suggest

Answer (score 0):

Uploading scenario cannot be done with selenium. You can use AutoIt to achieve it.
It is possible to open two different tabs and work with different Url in a single session.

Example(C#):
1. To open a new tab:

```
 IWebElement body = driver.FindElement(By.TagName("body"));  
 body.SendKeys(Keys.Control + 't');
```

or

```
 driver.ExecuteScript("window.open('your url','_blank');");
```

2.To switch between browser tabs: Get the window handle(window id's) of opened tabs by

```
var d =driver.WindowHandles;
```

3. To switch between browser tabs

```
driver.SwitchTo().Window(window-id);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do Web Interface tests with Java + Selenium, I advise you to use the [NoraUi](https://noraui.github.io/) Open Source Framework.

This Framework manage multiple-application and multiple-data (user, manager, ...).